# How to find last inserted varchar value in a table using MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table **student**, table structure is follow

```
student_id | name | class|
-------------------------
2-12-2013 | test | 3    |
-------------------------
2-13-2013 |test2 | 5    |
-------------------------
```

in this table i want add new record, its student_id become **2-14-2013**. For that i want to get the last inserted student_id. how can i get it by **MySQL query**. Am alredy use  `mysql_insert_id()`    But its not working, How to solve this issue?

Comment: you can add a auto increment column as `id` and then use `mysql_insert_id`

Comment: mysql_insert_id() triggers only if the last inserted primary key is auto incremented http://in2.php.net/mysql_insert_id

Comment: do you have any primarykey set in your table?

Comment: one more option is that use a `create_date` column int(10) and store timestamp to it and when you want to get last inserted record you can get a record of largest timestamp

Comment: student_id is the primary key and its each part have different meaning, its special type of id to avoid chances duplication

Comment: 'Satish Sharma' its a working solution, but a have this same issue in several table. so adding new field is not a practical solution for me

Answer (score 1):

Define Your student table like below:-

```
student_id | add_date  | name | class|
--------------------------------------
1          | 2013-12-2 | test | 3    |
--------------------------------------
2          | 2013-13-2 |test2 | 5    |
--------------------------------------
```

**student_id would be int auto increamented primary key**

then execute Query like below to get last inserted id:-

```
select student_id from student order by student_id desc limit 1;
```

Comment: suppose 2 users are addind record on same time then how could get exact last inserted ID?

Comment: @ChintanGor I think You are not experience in mysql. check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: LOL ma'am I think I am noe experienced as you but I can understand that if ever time order by ID return return only descending value , 
You are right in single user's Node what happens if multiple users are inserting data over same time 
 at that time i will receive your  inserted id

Comment: @ChintanGor You try to execute my answer. and execute it according to Your requirement. then if it doesn't give You expected result then let me know. and according to Your comment " if multiple users are inserting data over same time at that time" - for this case also id will be unique.

Comment: just think if this thing can be done then what purpose PHP gives lastinserted id function in MYSQL driver

Comment: Your table structure is right but the way you fetching last inserted id 
select student_id from student order by student_id desc limit 1;
is wrong
if you did not like my Down vote then I can Up it again but this is truth that we can not use last inserted id like this

Answer (score 1):

Hi You has to set primary key to your table as integer auto-increment then you can use this last inserted id

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "chirag2");
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_student ( student_id,name,class)values('3-12-2013','test1','3' )";
$res = mysql_query($con, $sql);

echo mysql_insert_id($con);
die;
```

Note: you need to truncate table before alter it and set new primary key to it so take backup before this